# Create a custom validation constraint that will check if a word begin with an uppercase - Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, customization, constraints, validation

I've followed this tutorial : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html to create a custom validation constraint.
I made it work, no problem.
The tutorial explains how to create a constraint that will only allow a user to type alphanumeric characters into a field.
What I want is to do create a constraint that will force the user to type a string beginning by an uppercase.

I guess I have to change this part of my function :

```
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
{
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Za0-9]+$/', $value, $matches)) {
        $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message, array('%string%' => $value));
    }
```

But I'm too new in php, and I don't know the syntax of the constraint I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find it myself regarding php.net :

```
if ($value[0]!=strtoupper($value[0])) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better solution is to use Regex validation constraints: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html

Example with annotation:

```
class MyEntity
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern="/^[A-Z]/",
     *     match=false,
     *     message="Your name cannot contain a number"
     * )
     */
    protected $string;
}
```

Comment: Hmhmh Ok, I'll take a look at it

Comment: Good addition Pi Wi :) Doesn't exactly answer the original question `"What I want is to do ` **create** `a constraint that will force the user to type a string beginning by an uppercase"` ... but for such a simple task the regex validator should indeed be used. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!preg_match('/^[A-Z]/', $value, $matches)) {
    $this->context->addViolation( /* .. */ );
}
```

`^` = begins with

`[A-Z]` = one of A ... Z ( an uppercase letter )